# Set Font only for Title Page Latex

Tags: fonts, titles, fontspec, titlesec

I want to change the font only for the title page
Right now, my code looks like this:

```
\begin{titlepage}   
    \raggedleft % Right align the title page

    \rule{1pt}{\textheight} % Vertical line
    \hspace{0.05\textwidth} % Whitespace between the vertical line and title page text
    \parbox[b]{0.75\textwidth}{ % Paragraph box for holding the title page text, adjust the width to move the title page left or right on the page
         {\large\textit{...... ...... ...... }}\\[4\baselineskip]

        {\Huge\bfseries Some Title}\\[2\baselineskip] % Title

        {\Large\textsc{Some Author}} % Author name, lower case for consistent small caps

        \vspace{0.47\textheight} % Whitespace between the title block and the publisher
        {\noindent a: b}\\[0.1\baselineskip]
        {\noindent c:d}\\[\baselineskip]
    }

\end{titlepage}
```

How would I add the font `\usepackage{stix}` to only the title page?

Comment: Have you tried something like `\begingroup
    \fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont
    \begin{stix}  
         your text here  
    \end{stix}  
\endgroup`?

Comment: @AML That doesnt do it. It moves my vertical line further to the left and it also says that it does not know `stix`

Comment: Easiest thing, as always i think, is doing a standalone file for the title page and include the pdf in the final document. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a single line at the beginning of the titlepage:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\fontfamily{stix}\selectfont
\raggedleft % Right align the title page

\rule{1pt}{\textheight} % Vertical line
\hspace{0.05\textwidth} % Whitespace between the vertical line and title page text
\parbox[b]{0.75\textwidth}{ % Paragraph box for holding the title page text, adjust the width to move the title page left or right on the page
     {\large\textit{...... ...... ...... }}\\[4\baselineskip]

    {\Huge\bfseries Some Title}\\[2\baselineskip] % Title

    {\Large\textsc{Some Author}} % Author name, lower case for consistent small caps

    \vspace{0.47\textheight} % Whitespace between the title block and the publisher
    {\noindent a: b}\\[0.1\baselineskip]
    {\noindent c:d}\\[\baselineskip]
}

\end{titlepage}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the code below, an MWE, the title page uses the stix font, observable with some of the extra math symbols I've added near the end of the title page. After the title page, you can set the font for the rest of the document to be something else, in this case, lmodern. You can disable the lmodern font selection to observe the effects on the text that follows the title page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}   

    \raggedleft % Right align the title page

    \rule{1pt}{\textheight} % Vertical line
    \hspace{0.05\textwidth} % Whitespace between the vertical line and title page text
    \parbox[b]{0.75\textwidth}{ % Paragraph box for holding the title page text, adjust the width to move the title page left or right on the page
        {\large\textit{...... ...... ...... }}\\[4\baselineskip]

        {\Huge\bfseries Some Title}\\[2\baselineskip] % Title

        {\Large\textsc{Some Author}} % Author name, lower case for consistent small caps

        \vspace{0.47\textheight} % Whitespace between the title block and the publisher
        {\noindent $\Gamma \Theta \Psi \chi$ a: b}\\[0.1\baselineskip]
        {\noindent c:d}\\[\baselineskip]
    }

\end{titlepage}

\fontfamily{lmodern}\selectfont

Some text, and a math formula \(a+b=\sqrt{c}\).

\end{document}
```

Hope this helps.